# How do I get the Postgresql configuration parameters from Heroku?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I'm creating a dashboard in Python Plotly that I want to push to Heroku, so I'm storing all the data in the Heroku postgresql database. I've followed [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/part-3-2-pandas-dataframe-to-postgresql-using-python-8dc0b0741226) on how to set this up which works. The only problem is instead of defining the connection parameters code I want to grab them from Heroku.

I'm assuming it's just a straight swap between the database url and explicitly stating the connection parameters. I've tried both of the following:

```
conn_params_dic = os.environ.get("<inserted database url from heroku web>")
conn = connect(conn_params_dic)
```

And

```
conn_params_dic = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
conn = connect(conn_params_dic)
```

But conn_params_dic just comes back as type None, so nothing is getting passed to the connection and I get the error `missing dsn and no parameters`. I've read through the documentation on Heroku but it doesn't seem overly clear to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using the Heroku addon for Postgres? If so, you should get a valid value for the `DATABASE_URL` env var. You can run `heroku addons -a <app>` to list the attached addons, and `heroku config -a <app>` to see the env vars that are set.

Comment: Yeah sorry so where I've put [insert database url from heroku web] is the DATABASE_URL that I get from ```heroku config -a <app>```, I thought it would be a security risk by including it. But when I pass that value to os.environ.get() and print ```conn_params_dic``` I'm getting the value None and the connection can't form because it's ```missing dsn and no parameters```